# Going on with no msvcrt.dll

Tags: c++, c, winapi, gcc, mingw

when i compile empty main in mingw i get 27kb exe and 1000 line disassembly,
generated exe is referencing kernel32.dll and msvcrt.dll

found somewghere that i can put "-nostdlib -Wl,--exclude-libs,msvcrt.a"
options and now generated exe is 3kb and has about 10 lines of assembly

thats fine, also dependency walker-like thing calls no references to anything

i would like to go on with the second form (stripped msvcrt.dll referency)
but be able to link to win32.dll-s to make winapi prog (but with no c-lib and stuff)

How to link to winapi dlls now, when i throwed out the msvcrt.dll? need i just add
some import libraries for winapi dlls or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add the libraries you need on the link command line:

```
gcc -c somefile.c
gcc -o someprogram somefile.o -nostdlib -luser32 -lshlwapi
```

You might also want to link libgcc statically using `-static-libgcc` to prevent the libgcc DLL pulling in msvcrt.dll.

Comment: do you maybe know which one are for most common winapi like message box and other base things?

Comment: ps seem to vork, very fine, tnx

Comment: @user2214913 I only know of `kernel32` and `user32`, but it really depends on what functions you call. I would suggest just searching for the function documentation on msdn, e.g. the one for the [´MessageBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505.aspx) function shows (near the bottom) that you need the `user32` library. It will also tell you what the correct header is you need to include for every function.

Comment: @user: All works, until things stop working. Without the CRT you will not have C (SEH) or C++-exception handling. You also don't have a properly initialized floating point environment, or properly initialized static data. There's also no support for 64-bit integers. The list goes on indefinitely.

Comment: @IInspectable is this lack of SEH some issue, how it would present to me? how serious this is?

Comment: @user: No SEH support means, that you cannot throw exceptions or gracefully handle those raised by 3rd party library code. Consequently, you cannot use the C++ Standard Library either, i.e. no `vector`, `string`, etc. However, I'd be more concerned that you have to implement your own memory manager, a facility that's also implemented in the CRT.